# Replace UINavigation with UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I've built a Navigation-based app, but now that I'm knee-deep in the code, I've decided it would actually be best to have just a UIToolbar instead (only need modal views, not drill-downs). But extricating the Navigation stuff and replacing it with a Toolbar is causing me all sorts of grief...

Has anyone ever done this, and maybe has a pointer or two? Or even know of a walkthrough linked somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do it programmatically or with IB?

Comment: A bit of both, I guess. So yeah, I've got the Navigation stuff in my RootView nib.

Comment: One of the things that's tripping me up is that since I've got CoreData going on, too, there are data management calls being passed around during the switches between UINav views... I don't want to break any of that (i.e., only have a modal view or two from the Toolbar, but still be able to refresh the table with CoreData calls).

Comment: Do you actually need to remove the navigation stuff?  There really isn't that much overhead.  What you are describing is like deciding after you have carpeted a floor that you want to change the wood you used on the sub-flooring -- far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I'm starting to see that, yeah. It's an HIG thing, though, in the end, as I won't be doing any drill-downs, so the nav bar at the top ends up as wasted space if it stays there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bite the bullet and rewrite.  Any guides out there will not be specific enough to your situation.

99 times out of a hundred if I realise I've made a massive design mistake and *don't* change it, I end up regretting it more than if I *do*.  And since you'll take a copy/start from scratch again, you can always revert if you need to give up half way through!

Seriously, because this is a current app that is still (relatively) early in its development life and is all fresh in your mind it will very likely be quick to re-do.  Also, sounds like this might be one of your first iPhone apps so you're likely learning new stuff every day - now you get to put all the new stuff in this app too.  And finally, just imagine the work involved if you put another 200 hours into this as it is and then decided you *had* to rewrite!!

Hope that helps, and I bet you get it rewritten in less than a day!

Comment: Heh, thanks. I think you're probably absolutely right. It is indeed my first major app attempt, and has already been rewritten from scratch at least a half-dozen times; I suppose once more won't kill me :)  Always worth taking a shot on here, as there's a great wealth of experience. Cheers.